# Scan my disk for geolocalized pictures close to a Wikidata item without an image

Tags: open-source, gis, exif, wikidata, wikimedia-commons

## Context

Many Wikipedia articles lack a picture, for instance most articles about Congolese towns or schools [do not have a picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Kindu).

So when I travel to out-of-the-beaten-path places I always take tons of pictures, thinking I will upload them to [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Kindu) and link them from the relevant [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3551608) article so that they can then easily be added to the articles in each language.

## Problem

Too many pictures and not enough time to upload them all. I need a tool that tells me what pictures are the most important, meaning the most susceptible to illustrate a Wikipedia article.

## How it could work

The tool could:

1. Scan my pictures folder, looking for pictures that are geolocalized (have a latitude and longitude in their EXIF).
2. For each geolocalized picture, check whether a nearby item needs a picture (possibly using [such a SPARQL query](https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/blob/master/app/src/main/resources/queries/nearby_query.rq)).
3. Show me a list or map of these place suggestions.
4. When I select a suggested place, display:

   - Information to help me judge whether the picture and article match:
   - an enlargeable thumbnail of the picture,
   - the Wikidata item or a summary of it,
   - the Wikipedia article (if it exists) or the first paragraph of it, preferably in one of the languages I know, sometimes maybe using automatic translation,
   - potentially for several pictures, if I took several pictures at that place.
   - Action:
   - "No" button, that I will click if the picture is not a picture of the item (for instance the picture is taken at that school but it just shows a cat). This choice is remembered by the tool, so that suggestion will not show up again next month.
   - "Yes" button, that I will click if the picture indeed is a good representation of the item.
5. Allow me to efficiently upload the picture, preferably with caption/description pre-filled using the Wikidata item's label, description and type.
6. Set the Wikidata item's `image` property to the identifier of the Wikimedia Commons picture.

## Requirements

- Free
- Open source